# How does meterpreter stay covert and undetected?

Tags: meterpreter

I've heard that meterpreter is really good at being stealthy and staying undetected. However, I can't seem to find articles detailing how it stays stealthy. I do know about encoders like "Shikata ga nai" and it's easy to figure that a C2 program would use encrypted channels.

What techniques does meterpreter generally use to stay stealthy once it's executed on a victim machine?

Comment: I think you are confusing being stealthy as a payload and being stealthy while running and being stealthy while communicating out, and you don't mention what you are being stealthy from. Meterpreter is, in fact, very easy to detect and anti-virus lights up like a Christmas tree when you run it on a machine with AV. So, what do you mean? Who says that it is stealthy?

Comment: @schroeder Maybe whoever I heard it from or my memory was wrong, but I remember it being "stealthy" in the context of a linux machine, like how you might not see it when running `ps aux`.

Comment: Not seeing the process in a process list is specific (and once you refine it to that, it's easy to look up): the command is `migrate`